# How do I set an image as an obstacle in a game?

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Snake!!</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href ="snake.css">
    </head>
    <body scroll="no" style="overflow: hidden">
        <div class="canvas-container">
            <img src="Apple.png" width="0" height="0" id="Apple"><!--Image-->
            <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas> <!-- canvas for the game-->
            <button type="button" onclick="restartGame()"class="Restartbutton" id="myButton">Restart</button>
            <textarea class="score"id="score" ></textarea>
            <script src="snake.js"></script>
        </div>



    </body>
</html>
```

```js
const Canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");<!-- start of JS-->
const ctx = Canvas.getContext("2d");
const imgApple = document.getElementById("Apple");

function draw(){
    ctx.drawImage(imgApple,200,200,50,50);<!-- just random numbers to place the Apple at-->
    ctx.fill();
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

I wanted to make an Snake game. I drew all the canvas and buttons for the game and now I just want to have a player or an Apple in the game as Images. I need help.
Thx already!

Comment: You should probably clear the canvas *first*, *then* draw the image.

Comment: Didnt work :( unfortunately

Comment: Do you have these invalid HTML comments in your actual JS code?

Comment: The default canvas size is 300x150, which means you're drawing the image outside the bounds. Use something like `<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>` to state the dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't specify initial dimensions for your canvas - thus it's using the defaults of width=300 and height=150. Of course this wouldn't be much of a problem if there wouldn't be this line:

```
ctx.drawImage(imgApple,200,200,50,50);
```

This means it tries to draw the apple at screen position x=200 and y=200 - outside of the visible area of the canvas.
Try it with

```
ctx.drawImage(imgApple,200,100,50,50);
```